# Sqlite: Trigger to restrict number of values in row

Tags: sqlite, database-trigger

I have a sqlite table in which product features are specified. The features, e.g. color, are in boolean columns. The columns are "1" or "NULL". Some features are exclusive. Since table structure is fixed, I tried to create a trigger raising an exception, which is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE productColor(
    productId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    isRed INTEGER,
    isBlue INTEGER,
    isYellow INTEGER,
    isBrown INTEGER)
```

The product can only have one color. My idea was to count columns in which more than one color is specified, i.e. less then three NULL-values. If there is at least one such row, the trigger is expect to raise an exception. So this is what my trigger looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onlyOneColor
    BEFORE INSERT ON productColor
    WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM 
        (SELECT ((CASE WHEN isBrown IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN isRed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN isBlue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN isYellow IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
        AS sumOfNulls FROM productColor) WHERE sumOfNulls<3)
    >=1
    BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'More then one color specified');
    END;
```

Comment: Which row(s) do you want to check? The one to be inserted, or any other(s)?

Comment: The one inserted would suffice. I guess a trigger set up as described checks all rows, but I wanted to tackle one problem at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a trigger; this can be done with check constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE productColor (
    productId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    isRed     INTEGER  CHECK (isRed    = 1 OR isRed    IS NULL),
    isBlue    INTEGER  CHECK (isBlue   = 1 OR isBlue   IS NULL),
    isYellow  INTEGER  CHECK (isYellow = 1 OR isYellow IS NULL),
    isBrown   INTEGER  CHECK (isBrown  = 1 OR isBrown  IS NULL),
    CHECK (ifnull(isRed,    0) + ifnull(isBlue,  0) +
           ifnull(isYellow, 0) + ifnull(isBrown, 0) <= 1)
);
```

If you stored all values as 0 or 1, these checks would be simpler. (`0` does not need any more storage space than `NULL`.)

---

If you really need a trigger, you can put the inverted conditions into the WHEN clause. (Please note that the values in the to-be-inserted row can be accessed with `NEW.isRed` etc.)

Comment: The solution with check contraints works great, I did not work on the trigger any further